# App runs in simulator but removes stack x/y constraints after running on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Wondering if anyone else has run into this problem and knows how to solve it. I have 3 vertical stack views, each consisting of a text view and label. They are all contained in one super stack view. The app runs fine for each device on the simmulator. When I connect my iphone and run on that device, I get missing constraints in the storyboard and the fields are all misaligned.  The strange thing is that even with the alignment errors, the app runs fine in all the simulated devices and my actual iPhone, with the alignment being perfect - not as seen on the storyboard. I have tried the various options - update constraints, update frames, reset to suggested constraints, etc. - but it doesn't get back to where it should be. I am working with a copy of my project.  I did File-Duplicate in the finder. It is really annoying because each time I have to backtrack.

[Picture of errors and messy screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C62dR.png)

Comment: The screenshot shows missing constraints in Interface Builder, not on a running app.  Have you added the missing X/Y constraint?

Comment: I did try adding constraints but had a problem making them what they should be. The weird thing was that the errors were still there but everything was fine on the running app. I am hoping the copy I made with "Duplicate" has solved the problem.  If so, the problem was with duplicating from the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching similar problems on the web and came across one post/article that mentioned downloading something called "Duplicate" to copy folders from the finder vs directly from the finder.

I downloaded it and followed instructions to copy the same folder my problem app was copied from. I ran it on all the simulator devices and my own iPhone without any issues. I'm hoping the problem was that everything wasn't copied over correctly from finder the first time and that now, using Duplicate, it is and it resolves the problem. I'll add to this if the subject problem emerges again.

[link to the post I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374245/cannot-start-xcode-6-1-1-after-duplicating-the-app-folder)